# Using Gitlab pages to publish jar file

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

I am using gitlab.io. I have a Java project which builds using Maven.

I have setup the following yml file to do the builds:

```
image: maven:3-jdk-7

build:
  script: 
  - "mvn install -B"
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r ./gl_pages/* .public
  - mv ./target/MyProg_installer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .public/Prog_Latest.jar
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

If I go to the following URL's I can see index.html without a problem.

```
https://<<MYUSER>>.gitlab.io/<<MY_PROJECT>/
https://<<MYUSER>>.gitlab.io/<<MY_PROJECT>/index.html
```

I expected

```
https://<<MYUSER>>.gitlab.io/<<MY_PROJECT>/Prog_Latest.jar
```

to enable me to download the jar file, but this url simply returns a 404.

I have downloaded the zip of the artifacts from the build and this works without an issue.

Am I doing something wrong?